# Match multi-line using python in linux

Tags: python, regex, linux

I met one problem when I used python regex in Linux. The target string has multi-line such as

```
This is a matched string_1.
This is a matched string_22.

Do not match this line.
```

What I want to do is match everything before "\n\n". I used

```
deleteString = re.compile('[\s\S]+\n\n')
```

but it's seems doesn't work in Linux.

How can I match the string before double \n.

Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regex in this case:

```
import re
import sys

text = sys.stdin.read()

# using str.find()
result = text[:text.find('\n\n') + 1]

# using re
result2 = re.match(r'(.*?)$^$', text, flags=re.DOTALL | re.MULTILINE).group(1)

# check that the result is the same
for r in [result, result2]:
     print(repr(r))
assert result == result2
```

#### [Output](http://ideone.com/3mUwGc)

```
'This is a matched string_1.\nThis is a matched string_22.\n'
'This is a matched string_1.\nThis is a matched string_22.\n'
```

If you're reading the input from a file in a text mode then Python automatically translates platform-specific newlines to '\n'.